# How do I get my Liquibase changeset to run if my SQL script changes?

Tags: mysql, liquibase, changeset

I’m using LIquibase 3.3 and MySQL 5.5.37.  I have this change set

```
<changeSet id="update-thirdparty-event-ids" author="davea" runOnChange="true">
    <sqlFile path="scripts/my_table_thirdparty_event_ids.sql"
             stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

I thought this changeset would run if I made changes to my SQL script.  However, I’m noticing that even when I change my script, the changeset will not run if it has already run once before.  What can I do to get the changeset to run if and only if my script changes?

Thanks, - Dave and

Comment: That's not how liquibase works. It is not about tracking your changing sql script. It's about tracking changes on the db. So each time you change something in your script you should actually create a new script and a new changeset and add those. Each changeSet is one change to the DB.

Comment: That's good to hear, but I don't want to do that.  I want the script to run if it changes.  If there's some hack to make that happen, I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the file save it with a different name so that you have to change the changeset definition to point to the new file.

<sqlFile path="scripts/my_table_thirdparty_event_ids **.rev3**.sql"
             stripComments="true"/>

Comment: I'm open to hacks, but this is a hack that other developers would not know to do if they inherited this code.  They would have to read our documentation, which no one does and which we don't do anyway.

Comment: There is some way to automate it - you can calculate checksum of the file and rename it/update xml file using Maven, for example. So file name will be changed and changset will be re-applied when file content is updated (there is a text substitute plugin, but because you will need to calc checksums etc I think that you will need to run some code yourself). You could have something like path="run_on_change scripts/my_table_thirdparty_event_ids.sql" So it is still a hack, but it is easier to support because it is automated. Also you could put your script into <sql></sql> tags in your changelog.

Comment: Then you are left only with keeping source files, and a generate target script files in some temp folder with a script and change the changeset file to point to that temp path where the files, that have different modification date than the source, have changed names. You would have orgfilename.sql in source folder and orgfilename-sometimestamp.sql in temp folder and you would match files by the first part of name to compare the modification date (and substitute with new timestamp if modificaiton date is older).